# How to have 2 different Master Details Page navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms

would like to know how to implement 2 Master Details page in a single Application.
Can this be workable? Any sample or code to follow.

**Update**

```
I m thinking to use this circular pattern, but I am not sure if this is a good idea.


 Launch ----->  MasterDetailDemo1   


1) in App.cs:

    MainPage = new MasterDetailDemo1();


2) at MasterDetailDemo1

   Click a Master2ndButton in Menu of MasterDetailDemo1 and goto MasterDetailDmo2

Master2ndButton
contain code:

    MainPage = new MasterDetailDemo2();


Back to First MasterDetailDemo1

Click a button in MasterDetailDemo2

BackToHome Button 
which contain code:

    MainPage = new MasterDetailDemo1()
```

Thanks

Comment: How would this work? Do you want a master detail with another master detail in the Detail view of the first one? If so I would advise against it because a user isn't familiar with it and I'm not even sure that it's possible. What kind of requirement are you trying to fulfil that needs something like that? There is probably another/better way.

Comment: @Steven, just want to try to find out is my solution workable.

Comment: Technically that could work.

Comment: @Steven,  This means MainPage of the App can be assigned to any Type of page (TabbedPage, NavigationPage...) to suite my needs. But will this cause any problem? if I choose to use this, I can not use Mvvm Navigation Pattern.

Comment: You can definetely use the MVVM navigation patterns. You're only setting the mainpage, which is the root of your navigation. Every navigation from that point onwards can be done using MVVM. You shouldn't be designing your application to constantly be swapping out the MainPage for other things though. Choose one that suits your needs (Tabs/MasterDetail) and stick to it.